# GIF 87a encoding in Java

Tags: java, gif

I've done some research to do a GIF (version 87a) encoder but there are some implementation specifics I can't find specially about the data blocks

- First, I can only check how many bytes each block will have when I reach either 255 bytes or the end of the image right? There's no way to tell in advance how many bytes I will need.
- Second, as the gif encoding is in little endian, how can I write the resulting integers of the LZW compression in java and how should I align them? I looked at ByteBuffer (I'm coding in Java) but as the integers won't necessarily fit in in a byte it won't work right? How should I do then?
- At last, between data blocks, should I start a new LZW compression or just continue where I left off in the previous block?

Comment: ByteBuffer will work fine for this. It has a method for setting byte order and methods for getting ints of varying length.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann the methods I see are write integers (4 bytes) or a byte. If I want to write bits that are not aligned to the byte what's the method I should use? Like 9 bits for each int for example.